# How many LEFT JOINS make a VIEW unusable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, view, execution-plan

I have a view which involves LEFT JOINS on 20+ tables to a base table but when querying this view and looking at the execution plans I am getting something totally unexpected.

For example, with the query below I would expect a clustered index seek on the table:

```
SELECT id FROM dbo.TableName WHERE id = 256
```

Whereas when I use the view I get the clustered index seek on the table along with 3 nested loops (left outer join).

```
SELECT id FROM dbo.ViewName WHERE id = 256
```

Why would this occur?
The above is a very simple example but when selecting additional columns from the view more and more unnecessary LEFT JOINS appear in the execution plan.

Comment: We'll need the queries and execution plans to answer this.

Comment: Related question on SO. [Joining 100 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14780307/73226)

Comment: Can you post a sample view and query from the view that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link provided by Martin Smith to an existing SO question provided me with the answer:

> The main restrictions are that foreign key relationships must be based
>   on a single key to contribute to the simplification process